# Is statistical query learning equivalent to correlational statistical query learning given a fixed distribution?

Tags: pac-learning

As title, I saw some [paper](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/varun.kanade/docs/computational-FK12.pdf) mentioned they are equivalent, but I'd wonder how to prove they are? is it something to do with PAC as SQ is a restricted version of PAC?

Comment: Did you see there references (Bshouty and Feldman, 2001; Feldman, 2008) given in that paper?

Comment: Yes. However, [Feldman 2008](https://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~mehlhorn/SeminarEvolvability/p619-feldman.pdf) seems Lemma 3.1 touches a bit on this topic, but not quite...
As for [Bshouty and Feldman 2001](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume2/bshouty02a/bshouty02a.pdf) I thought it could be lemma 30, but I am not really sure how is it related.